# Simplify complex expression so that it's manifestly real if the parameter $a$ is real.

Tags: complex-numbers

I am stuck on a problem. The problem sheet states that I have to simplify the following expression:
$$\frac{2\pi\textrm{i}\textrm{e}^{\textrm{i}\pi a/3}\textrm{e}^{-2\pi\textrm{i}/3}}{1-\textrm{e}^{2\pi\textrm{i}a/3}\textrm{e}^{2\pi\textrm{i}/3}}$$

So that it is "manifestly" real if the parameter $a$ is also real. I don't understand what is being asked. Does it mean that I have to modify it until it becomes obvious that the expression results in a real number if a is replaced by a real number, too? What would be the best course of action?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If we multiply numerator and denominator with $e^{-\pi i(a+1)/3}$, we get
$$
\frac{
2\pi i e^{-2\pi i/3} e^{-\pi i /3}
}{
e^{-\pi i(a+1)/3}-e^{\pi i(a+1)/3}
}
$$
We can now make use of $\sin(\varphi)=\frac{e^{i\varphi}-e^{-i\varphi}}{2i}$ and we get
$$
\frac{
\pi e^{-\pi i}
}{
-\sin(\pi (a+1)/3)
}
$$
Making use of $e^{-\pi i}=-1$, we get
$$
\frac{
\pi
}{
\sin(\pi (a+1)/3)
}
$$
from which we can directly see that the result is real if $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a\not\equiv 2\pmod{3}.$

Comment: Thanks, Reinhard. I was having trouble finding a way of doing this. I've reworked this problem and similar ones to understand each step better. Thanks again!